# Can I simplify this even more? in regards to ln

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

say that I had an equation: $y=\ln(x^3+C)$, is there any way to get $C$, an arbitrary constant out of the log? This was the general solution I came to for one of the differential equation exercises, but I want to know if it would be appropriate to leave it as it is, seeing that, as an example $e^{2x+C}$ would be simplified to $Ce^{2x}$. As far as I know, there is no way of pulling the '$b$' out of $\ln(a+b)$, so I'm just looking for confirmation that my original answer is simplified enough.

On a side note, referring back to this example: $e^{2x+C}$, can I've seen people use $A$ to represent the general solution so like $Ae^{2x}$, where $A = \pm e^ce^{2x}$. Is it crucial to use $A$ instead of $C$? And do you have to say what $A$ also represent?
Thanks

Comment: It is fine as you have written it(I assume you ask from an exam perspective). There are no further simplifications for $y=\ln(x^3+c)$, an equivalent form could be $x^3-e^y=b$, where $b$ is an arbitrary constant. IMO any of the equivalent forms are good enough. Don't fret too much over it.

Comment: On your other question, it is customary (but not _essential_) to use $ \ C \ $ for unspecified _additive_ constants and $ \ A \ $ for unspecified _multiplicative_ constants.